# Environment looks fine in rendered preview mode, but completely black in final render?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, light

My environment and render settings all seem normal, and when I go into rendered mode(Shift+Z or preview mode dropdown menu) it looks fine and lights the scene normally, but when I do a test render of the final frame, the environment disappears and doesn't light the scene or show up in reflections. I thought it might be my compositing setup somehow, but it looks like that while it's still doing the initial render, and I tried just plugging the rendered image into the final image slot to test it and it still looks the same.

Screenshots:

[image: preview and render settings part 1]

[image: part 2]

[image: render and environment settings]

[image: compositing and camera settings]

Comment: You probably excluded environment from the current render layer.

Comment: In what setting?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Environment in your render layers:

[image]

set film to transparent:

[image]

Composite over the background using alpha over:

[image]

Comment: The environment pass still renders as black, and still doesn't light the scene.