# World appearing black

Tags: rendering, world, compositing-nodes

[image]For some reason, whenever I do a test render with Shift + Z, all I get is my character and the world is black. In the World properties, I have a Sky Texture with a strength of four, but it still shows as black. The only thing it effects is my character. Also, I'm wondering if this is related to why I can't get my character's shadows to render/show on a separate Render Layer...? I do have some Nodes set up, but deleting all of those hasn't fixed the issue, so I'm not sure if they're to blame.

Any advice?

[image]

Comment: in the Render settings is Film/Transparent checked?

Comment: Ahh, yes, of course. I totally forgot about that. Thank you. :D

Comment: I don't really see the point in creating a new thread because, to me, it's the same issue. My compositing is pretty much finished, but when I go to render, the video footage isn't being rendered out. My character does, but everything else is a black screen. I've attached an image of my node setup.

Comment: You need to learn how to troubleshoot your nodes with a viewer node. Switch the bottom window from the time line to a UV/image editor. Render by pressing  f12 so that the compositor has some information to work from and then plug in the viewer node to the beginning of your node tree so that you can understand what each element is and how is getting transformed along the chain.  Other advise: Images with alpha are better combined with an Alpha over node. Also, NEVER use the slider labeled "premultiplied". Alpha channel can be Premultiplied or not, Half way makes no sense at all.

Comment: Read: [Environment looks fine in rendered preview mode, but completely black in final render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99466/environment-looks-fine-in-rendered-preview-mode-but-completely-black-in-final-r/99467#99467)

Comment: I have a Viewer node set up, though it's at the end of the tree. I also have an Alpha Over node in there and I tried setting Environment on with both layers. I'm still getting a black screen though.

Comment: I can't get the Viewer node to work either. I get what it's supposed to do, but connecting it to each node isn't doing anything from what I can see. I'm not seeing any changes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with Blender 2.8

This worked for me :-

under View Layer tab, select Filter drop down and make sure that the Environment Checkbox is checked

Hope this helps